# How to merge and align contents of 2 separate files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 2 separate files consisting of 2 columns each. One of the Columns in each file would have some matching data and each file having a 2nd column of data unique to that file. Also the matching columns might not be complete in each file Example:

File 1

```
Shelf1   Apples
Shelf2   Pears
Shelf3   Oranges
Shelf4   Plums
```

File 2

```
Shelf1   Restock
Shelf2   Out_of_Season
Shelf4   Full
```

Desired Output:

```
Shelf1   Apples    Restock
Shelf2   Pears     Out_of_Season
Shelf3   Oranges
Shelf4   Plums     Full
```

Note Shelf3 had no entry in File 2 would expect the output for that text to be blank for that column in the desired output. Been playing with sort and merge in bash and also some array's but haven't had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think such question was answered man-many times on SO

Comment: Are the files sorted? Are the values in column 1 unique?

Comment: They are sorted numerically for the common column in each file. However one of the files has gaps, for example shelf 3 was missing in File2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` with `-a` option for unmatched fields, read `man join`:

```
kent$  join -a1 file1 file2
Shelf1 Apples Restock
Shelf2 Pears Out_of_Season
Shelf3 Oranges
Shelf4 Plums Full
```

If the output format (alignment) does matter, pipe the join output to `column -t` like:

```
join -a1 f1 f2|column -t
```

Comment: Thanks Kent! I tried to upvote your response but it won't let me. Since I have no reputation here yet. Much appreciated!